# how to manage DB connection pool under sharded environment?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, connection-pooling, sharding

My web application need to support scalability at both Web and DB tier.
I have the following components:

1. N Web servers (Tomcat)
2. M DB servers sharded by username as the shard key (PostgreSQL)

Our shard strategy as following:

1. The shard strategy is lookup table based, we have one index table (username,shardId), the other shard table (shardId,connectionString,loading).
2. We will monitor the shard DB periodically, and update the loading status field.
3. When create new user, we always pickup the shard with lowest loading, and store to index table.
4. The DB shards will be added or removed dynamically.

I have to implement an API like `getDBConnection(username)` to get one JDBC connection according to the shard key (in this case the login user).

The questions are :

1.How could I implement this API in a way that will work with a connection pool? Suppose each shard support 500 connections, how could i did this via Java code?

Comment: What connection pool are you using? `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool`? `dbcp`? `c3p0`? Something else? (BTW, I didn't downvote, but I can see why whoever did: it takes a bit of reading before it's clear what you're asking, and you've omitted a lot of important detail).

Comment: BTW, you should almost always shard according to a *hash* of a key, not the key its self. That way you get a more uniform distribution across the shards and don't land up with the shard with usernames 'a-c' melting while the 'x-z' shard sits nearly idle. Use bucket hashing.

Comment: @Craig any pool implementation should work for me.You know the shard IP is dynamically, so i need to create DB connection dynamically, rather than define DS in spring XML.Just don't know how to go.

Comment: @Craig for the shard selection strategy, we design via lookup table such as <username,shardID> where shard info saved in <shardID,connectionString,loading>. We will monitor some data related to shard to give its loading status. When pickup one shard for new user, we always pick the shard with lowest loading.

Comment: " not a real question" - Ya right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably wouldn't connection pool in the application at all, I'd probably just use server-side connection pooling with `pgpool-II` or `pgbouncer`.

If I was to use in-application pooling I'd create per-shard connection pools and just pick a connection out of the appropriate pool for the shard. This will work with any connection pool implementation that lets you create pools programmatically, rather than declaratively. Each pool should try to close inactive connections quite aggressively. It looks like `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` is suitable for this; see [the Tomcat JDBC pool docs](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html).

Since this will result in potentially large numbers of connections sitting around and lots of connects/disconnects, it will be very important to also run a server side connection pool to limit and share connections to each shard. Use something like `pgbouncer` or `pgpool-II` in transaction pooling mode on each shard to share a relatively small number of real PostgreSQL connections out among the larger number of connections from web workers.

I'd say you'll want a pattern like this:

```
web1 [pool1]-----------------------------[server1-pgbouncer]------[server1-pg]
     [pool2]-------------------------------v         ^
     [pool3]---------v        [server2-pgbouncer]-----------------[server2-pg]
                     |                     ^         |
                    [server3-pgbouncer]---------------------------[server3-pg]
                     |                     |         |
web2 [pool3]---------^                     |         |
     [pool2]-------------------------------|         |
     [pool1]------------------------------------------
```

where each app pool connects to a pgbouncer on the shard server corresponding to that pool, and only that shard server's pgbouncer ever talks to the shard's PostgreSQL instance.

Comment: thanks for your quick comment, i will have a try pgbouncer or pgpool-II. But currently we prefer implement this layer in our application, so maybe go with DBCP or C3P0 programmatically is one possible sulution.

Comment: @Grace I'd say you'll *have* to use programmatic connection pool management, but you *really* will also want to have the servers behind a pgbouncer, or you'll have lots of idle backends wasting memory and other resources and you'll be starting/stoppping backends more often than you have to.

Comment: To start simple, i would like to implement PostgreSQL monitoring/fail over via application layer.Just look into pgbouncer and pgpool2 which seems able to work. I prefer to deploy pgbouncer instance on each shard DB server. Is there any issues for such usage?

Comment: @Grace No, there isn't; that's exactly how I'd recommend doing it.

Comment: many thanks for your great support!